What is this circuit in this UBLOX M9N GPS module?

I recently opened up this CUAV NEO 3 GPS module and found the UBLOX-NEOM9N GPS module Product Page, after understanding the two removed ICs were a SAW and an LNA for the L1 band and this leads to a ceramic passive patch antenna, I am curious what this circuit in red is. It seems to be composed of three capacitors and an RF inductor. I looked up a bias Tee circuit but am not sure this is one. I would love to know what this circuit is and how it works!

This is a matching network, from the module's input impedance to the antenna's impedance, usually 50 Ohms.

I always thought matching was done by setting the trace width for the given stack up and the saw and lna already had an intrinsic 50 ohm impedance! Is this additional matching network because the rf trace exceeds it's critical length?

FR4 has relatively loose tolerances with regard to Er, it can be anywhere from 3.2 to 4.8, depending on the source material.
